# Link with Icon ::before, should break nicely when multiline

Tags: html, css

I have declared all my text links with an icon right before it.
Works as expected. Just in the case the link text is very long and breaks onto a second line, it does not look good.

Current situation (when breaking) is:

```
> This linktext 
is very long
and breaks awful
```

I wish it could be

```
> This linktext 
  is very long
  but breaks nicely
```

How can this be achieved?

```css
.container { 
  width: 100px; 
  border: solid 1px #ddd; 
}

a::before { 
  content: ">";
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <a href="#">This textlink is very long and should break nicely</a>
  
</div>
```

Comment: In a multitude of different ways … Give the link a padding, move the icon to the left using a negative margin; or make the link flexbox; or …

Comment: a { padding: 10px; }  a::before { margin-left: -10px; } does not work. Do you have a working sample?

Comment: You’ll need to make the link itself `inline-block` or `block`, otherwise the padding will only apply to the first line.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Would you mind and write an official answer so that I can accept this and other people (who are searching for a solution on the same question) could easily find it?

Comment: Sure, no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple way to achieve this, is to give the link a bit of padding on the left, to move its whole content over a bit - and then moving the icon back to the left using a negative margin.

(I added an explicit width to the icon here as well, then it works a bit better. Otherwise you’d have to figure out a very specific pixel value that works, or else the first line of text might get offset a bit differently than the rest of them.)

```css
.container {
  width: 100px;
  border: solid 1px #ddd;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

a::before {
  content: ">";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <a href="#">This textlink is very long and should break nicely</a>

</div>
```

There’s multiple other ways this could be achieved as well. The icon might be absolutely positioned instead of move by a negative margin, or the whole link could be made into a flexbox element … but the method shown here is quite simple and low complexity, so I still often use it in cases like this.

Answer (score 1):

This should be what you want

```
a {
  display: block;
  padding-left: 15px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
}

a::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: ">";
  margin-right: 5px;
  left: 0;
}
```

Comment: ah, the container was only for sample purpose, so that the links breaks very soon. Usually I do not have such a container on my page. Sorry!!

Comment: @JonSnow You can even do it with <a> element just add on it display: block; if you want to limit <a> width

Comment: EDITED answer for element <a>